# Contact form with file attachment?

Tags: forms, php

I have a contact form which is a template for pages on wordpress that I use if I need a contact form. All works fine but I want to add the capability of adding a file attachment so when the user fills in their name etc they can upload a photo and that photo will be sent to be me as an attachment.

I have a perfect working contact form and I only want to add that functionality to it. All my current code does all this it sends the name of the person their email address and their message to my email, all I'm missing is the attachment feature. I've been looking at alot of contact forms with this feature but to integrate that feature to my sendmail.php seems very hard as the coding style is completely different. Here is a demo of this in action. [demo](http://www.pstoots.com/contact/)

This is my php file that has the form in it.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#contact').ajaxForm(function(data) {
                 if (data==1){
                     $('#success').fadeIn("slow");
                     $('#bademail').fadeOut("slow");
                     $('#badserver').fadeOut("slow");
                     $('#contact').resetForm();
                     }
                 else if (data==2){
                         $('#badserver').fadeIn("slow");
                      }
                 else if (data==3)
                    {
                     $('#bademail').fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                    });
                 });
        </script>
<!-- begin colLeft -->
    <div id="colLeft">
    <!-- Begin .postBox -->
        <div class="postBox">
            <div class="postBoxTop"></div>
            <div class="postBoxMid">
                <div class="postBoxMidInner first clearfix">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p><?php echo get_option('alltuts_contact_text')?></p>

            <p id="success" class="successmsg" style="display:none;">Your email has been sent! Thank you!</p>

            <p id="bademail" class="errormsg" style="display:none;">Please enter your name, a message and a valid email address.</p>
            <p id="badserver" class="errormsg" style="display:none;">Your email failed. Try again later.</p>

            <form id="contact" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sendmail.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Your name: *</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameinput" name="name" value=""/>
            <label for="email">Your email: *</label>

                <input type="text" id="emailinput" name="email" value=""/>
            <label for="comment">Your message: *</label>
                <textarea cols="20" rows="7" id="commentinput" name="comment"></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" id="submitinput" name="submit" class="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="receiver" name="receiver" value="<?php echo strhex(get_option('alltuts_contact_email'))?>"/>
            </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postBoxBottom"></div>
        </div>
     <!-- End .postBox -->
    </div>
    <!-- end colleft -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and here is the file that handles the sending of the mail.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      error_reporting(E_NOTICE);
      function valid_email($str)
      {
      return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
         }
      if($_POST['name']!='' && $_POST['email']!='' && valid_email($_POST['email'])==TRUE && strlen($_POST['comment'])>1)
      {
          $to = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", hexstr($_POST['receiver']));
          $from = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $_POST['email']);
          $subject = "Website contact message from ".$_POST['name'];
          $message = $_POST['comment'];

          $match = "/(bcc:|cc:|content\-type:)/i";
            if (preg_match($match, $to) ||
                preg_match($match, $from) ||
                preg_match($match, $message)) {
              die("Header injection detected.");
            }
          $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
          $headers .= "Reply-to: ".$from."\r\n";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
          {
              echo 1; //SUCCESS
          }
          else {
              echo 2; //FAILURE - server failure
          }
      }
      else {
      echo 3; //FAILURE - not valid email

      }
      }else{
         die("Direct access not allowed!");
       }
        function hexstr($hexstr) {
              $hexstr = str_replace(' ', '', $hexstr);
              $hexstr = str_replace('\x', '', $hexstr);
              $retstr = pack('H*', $hexstr);
              return $retstr;
            }
  ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can read this simple tutorial to know what needs to be done to add file upload support to your current form:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Hope it helps!

**EDITED**

---

After the upload process, you can do like this:

```
if (file_exists($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'])) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
}
```

What this does is to add an attachment to your email by calling the AddAttachment from PHPMailer, and using the file just uploaded from the TMP folder of your server... so no actual storage of the file is necessary.

Comment: @Zull I don't want something to be uploaded. An image is attached to the email, without being stored on the server etc. Thank you though!

Comment: @Stam: sorry, my bad! Never the less, if you want to attach the image to the email, you need to make a normal upload but instead of storing the image to the server, you attach it to the email... So, you don't "moveuploadedfile" to anywhere, you just add an attachment to your email!

Comment: Ok cool and how do i do the final part of adding it actually as an attachment?

Comment: @Stam: Just edited my answer to include the "AddAttachment" part of PHPMailer's Class with reference to the temporary uploaded file by your form. Assuming as "uploaded" the name for your input file type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

It has a option for Upload field as well as all validations, really easy to use.

You just need to enter shortcode and you can use the contact form anywhere you want.